# What's the best practice for React integrate scss?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

My scss directory in project:

```
src/styles/
├── base
│   ├── _global.scss
│   └── _normalize.scss
├── libraries
│   └── _antd-custom.scss
├── utilities
│   └── _utilities.scss
├── variables
│   └── _colors.scss
├── base.scss
└── settings.scss
```

The **base.scss** import global and basic scss files:

```
@import 'src/styles/base/normalize';
@import 'src/styles/base/global';

@import 'src/styles/libraries/antd-custom';
@import 'src/styles/utilities/utilities';
```

The **settings.scss** import config styles like variables, mixins, functions .e.g.

```
@import 'src/styles/variables/colors';
```

And the `settings.scss` will be loaded before other scss files.

**webpack.conf.js**

```
rules: [
  // styles
  {
    test: /\.(s)css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins() {
            return [autoprefixer()]
          },
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          // load settings scss files before
          data: '@import "src/styles/settings.scss";',
        },
      },
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
}
```

The `base.scss` will be imported in app entrypoint:

**src/index.js**

```
import 'src/styles/base.scss'
```

The result is that `settings.scss` works but not `base.scss`.

Should I import both `setting.scss` and `base.scss` files in webpack **sass loader** options? Or any other better solutions?